# Lodash - Merge object from another array with same key as sub object to main array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const parentDetails = [
    {
        'name': '5003',
        'id': '1'
    },
    {
        'name': '5000',
        'id': '2'
    }
];
const childrenDetails = [
    {
        'cid': '11',
        'Reference': '5003'
    },
    {
        'cid': '22',
        'Reference': '5000'
    }
];
```

Desired Output using `lodash` library: Extract matching `reference` from the second array with the `name` of the first array and append the matching child detail as an object to the first array as shown below. The result should not mutate the original array.

```
result = [
    {
        'name': '5003',
        'id': '1',
        'childrenDetail' : {
            'cid': '11',
            'Reference': '5003'
        }
    },
    {
        'name': '5000',
        'id': '2',
        'childrenDetail' : {
            'cid': '22',
            'Reference': '5000'
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: I don't think you need `lodash` for this, what have you tried so far?

Comment: `result = [];
for (const i of parentDetails ) {
    for (const j of childrenDetails ) {
        if (i.name === j.reference) {
            i.childrenDetail = j;
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I want the same output using lodash library. This is part of a task.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `_.find()`

```
const result = parentDetails.map(elm => {
   const childrenDetail = _.find(childrenDetails, elm2 => elm2.Reference === elm.name);
   if (childrenDetail) return ({...elm, childrenDetail});
});
console.log(result);
```

You can also replace `array.map()` with  `_.map()`.